# Rails postgres hstore - how to ommit a nil input value from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I have a form that displays inputs based on user preferences.  I am storing the values as an hstore hash since I dont know ahead of time exactly what the form input for each user will be.  The problem I am running in to is that even though a user has an input preferenced doesnt mean they have to enter a value for it each time.  Which, can result in :foo => "".

All the doc examples show you how to find records you know the key name of.  In my case, I dont know the key name...I need to find all the keys in a hash whose value => "".

Then, I should be able to do something like the docs shows...for each empty value

person.destroy_key(:data, :foo).destroy_key(:data, :bar).save

avals(hstore) is likely what I need to user...  How do you use avals with rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since hstore is just a hash in rails...you just need to evaluate the hash before saving it.

...in model

```
  before_save :remove_blanks

  private

  def remove_blanks
    self.hstore = self.hstore.reject{ |k,v| v.blank? }
  end
```

replace 'hstore' with your hstore column name